# Python if function with multiple conditions including none

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make an if statement that checks for 2 things:
1)if x is None
2)if x is [] (empty list)

However I can't seem to combine the two into one equation

This is what I tried:

```
x = None
if x is not None or x != []:
print("x is not none or empty list")
```

desired result in this situation is that it prints nothing, but it still prints out.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that if x is None then it isn't an empty list so this still evaluates to true. You can either do `if x is not None and x != []:` or `if not(x is None or x == []):`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an and statement:

```py
if x is not None and x!=[]:
   print('output')
```

or i you want to use an or statement for any reason:

```py
if not(x is None or x == []):
   print('output')
```

Your problem is that if `x == None` x isn't empty and the the result is `true`.

Comment: I made a small edit to fix your second example where you accidentally had 'and' instead of 'or'